# how do I use a method from one class in another class (is it possible)

Tags: python, oop, methods

I have a bank account program that monitors savings, checking, and business accounts and I want to be able to transfer some money out of the savings account and into the checking account when prompted.

I have a move_to_checking method in the savings class and a grab_from_savings method in the checking class. the move_to_checking method works as desired by removing the amount given from the savings total but the grab_from_savings method won't add the amount to the checking total.

```py
class CheckingAccount(Account):

    def __init__(self, cust_id, checking_total_amount):
        Account.__init__(self, cust_id) 
        self.checking_total_amount = checking_total_amount

    def grab_from_savings(self):
        moved_amount = 0
        moved_amount.move_to_checking()
        self.checking_total_amount += moved_amount.move_to_checking()

        return self.checking_total_amount


class SavingsAccount(Account):

    def __init__(self, cust_id, savings_total_amount):
        Account.__init__(self, cust_id)
        self.savings_total_amount = savings_total_amount

    def move_to_checking(self, amount_to_move):
        if amount_to_move <= self.savings_total_amount:
            self.savings_total_amount -= amount_to_move
            return amount_to_move
        else:
            return "insufficient funds!"

chck_1 = CheckingAccount('Jackson', 200)
savings_1 = SavingsAccount('Jackson', 500)
savings_1.move_to_checking(100)
print(savings_1)
chck_1.grab_from_savings()
```

I want the result to yield $400 left in the savings account and the $100 added to the checking account leaving that with $300. The savings account prints $400 but the checking yields an `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'move_to_checking'`.

Comment: Read the error, it has nothing to do with not being able to access the function. Show the traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that an integer has no method called `move_to_checking`. In `grab_from_savings`, the variable `moved_amount` is the integer zero.

I think a better way to put what's going on into Object Oriented Land is by creating a `BankAccount` class that contains both a checking `Account` and a savings `Account`. Then the semantics of moving money between accounts make more sense.

```py
class Account:
    def __init__(self, cust_id, checking_total_amount):
        self.cust_id = cust_id
        self.total_amount = total_amount

    def add_funds(self, funds):
        self.total_amount += funds
        return self.total_amount

    def remove_funds(self, funds):
        if funds > self.total_amount:
            raise ValueError('insufficient funds!')
        self.total_amount -= funds
        return self.total_amount


class BankAccount:

    def __init__(self, cust_id, checking_total, savings_total):
        self.cust_id = cust_id
        self.checking = Account(cust_id, checking_total)
        self.savings = Account(cust_id, savings_total)

    def move_to_checking(self, amount_to_move):
        # remove_funds will throw an error if there are insufficient funds
        self.savings.remove_funds(amount_to_move)
        self.checking.add_funds(amount_to_move)

jacksons_account = BankAccount('Jackson', 200, 500)
jacksons_account.move_to_checking(100)
print(jacksons_account.savings.total_amount)
```

Comment: I understand now that moved_amount is = 0 and thats why it's throwing the error but Is there anyway to get what's returned in move_to_checking to be added to self.checking_total_amount?

Comment: You can do it explicitly at the bottom with something like `chck_1.grab_from_savings(savings_1.move_to_checking(100))`, if you modify `grab_from_savings` to take the amount as a an input parameter.